# How to render custom SVG in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am getting below error while trying to render custom SVG in LWC

> [Failed to execute 'setAttributeNS' on 'Element':
>   'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' is an invalid namespace for
>   attributes.]

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/247505/edit) with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) as how are you trying to render the SVG? This will let anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying so that we may know what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_svg) from lwc documentation on how to do it.

```
// myComponent.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import SVG_URL from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/svg_url';

export default class myComponent extends LightningElement {
    get svgURL {
        return SVG_URL;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- myComponent.html -->
<template>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <use xlink:href={svgURL}></use>
    </svg>
</template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work in IE :( Any recommendations how to do it in IE?

Comment: use img tag <img src = {src}></img>

Comment: Hey, that link to the documentation is old. The current page is this one - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_svg (the previous one had an error). Can you update it? Thanks

Comment: thanks, updated the link

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here really provide a complete solution to the issue most people likely have when they searched this.

If you are trying to use a custom SVG within Lightning Web Components, not as the icon for the Component itself in the builder, this answer is for you.

In order to use svg in the `<use>` tag of the svg as you see in all the examples, you must first make sure your svg file has a `<g>` tag wrapped around all of the content you wish to use and that tag needs an id.

Rather than just returning the url returned by importing the resource, append the id to the end like so

```
get svgURL() {
    return SVG_URL + '#layer1';
}
```

You can then reference this getter method in one of these two ways:

```
<!-- Option 1 -->
<lightning-icon src={svgURL}></lightning-icon>

<!-- Option 2 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use xlink:href={svgURL}></use>
</svg>
```

This is from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/documentation) for `<lightning-icon>`

Chances are the aspect ratio/viewbox of your svg image won't match what `<lightning-icon>` uses, and if that's the case use Option two and specify the same viewbox as the custom svg file on the new `svg` tag.

For more information on viewbox and svg scaling, (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/19485375/9565551] is a lovely answer about it.

Comment: Hi @stackasaur, Option 1 is very cool, but it is not possible to change the color of the icon, right? Classes with fill don't work in LWC for inner components, so I was using Option 2 to display custom SVGs, but it turned out that they are not rendered in IE11. I load icons from static resources. Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: @Jm, the issue with IE is that it doesn't support external url references in SVG use tags. I suppose static resources are considered external even though they'd be from the same domain. What you can try is editing your SVG file in a text editor and copy and paste the whole `<g>` you are referencing. Give it a different id and change the color here. Then you can use your JS code to switch between which reference is being used. Make sense?

Comment: Yeah, I know this solution, but I want my code to be fully dynamic, so it doesn't make sense to copy-paste from static resource in this case. For now I used `<img>` tag to display icon in the IE. It works but I didn't find any solution to change the color. Anyway, it is enough for now. Thanks for your answer, it is cool if you don't have to support IE ;)

Answer (score -1):

I am using icon-name to render custom svg, and it works fine:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account Dashboard" icon-name="custom:custom19">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <svg class="d3" width={svgWidth} height={svgHeight} lwc:dom="manual"></svg>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/103718)